# Integrating Chartboost on Mono for Android

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to use Chartboost in my Mono for Android game.
I downloaded the latest chartboost Jar files, and created a new Java Bindings Library project,
but Im getting a few build errors, like

`The type or namespace name 'AbstractObjectSerializer' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Mongodb.Util'.`

Has anyone successfully built this library, for use in Mono for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been [answered](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/804/chartboost#latest) at Xamarin's [forums board](http://forums.xamarin.com/) by Xamarin staff. The solution basically consists on [enabling diagnostic build output](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Deployment%2C_Testing%2C_and_Metrics/Diagnostics#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output), which hopefully let you know why the *AbstractObjectSerializer* isn't being bound. You may then be able to work around the issue using [Transforms\Metadata.xml](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Binding_API_Metadata_Reference).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Lance ok, I copied the answer with a reference to the original source to give credit to the original author.